# Just say no vs dealbreaker

Tags: monopoly-deal

If player 1 plays a dealbreaker for player 2, can player 3 place a just say no card or can it only be the person the card is played to? In this example, can only player 2 place a just say no?

Answer (score 2):

Player 3 is not able to counter the "**DEAL BREAKER**" card.

As per the rules text on the card, you can only play a "**JUST SAY NO!**" card when an action has been played against *you*, you can't play it to cancel action cards played against other players.

[image]